# JS removeNode problem FF 4.01

Tags: javascript

Can someone check this for me:

```
function on_message_start () {
    messageDiv = document.getElementById("on_message");

    //add close button
    aClose = document.createElement("a");
    aClose.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aClose.setAttribute("id", "messageClose");
    textClose = document.createTextNode("Close");
    messageDiv.appendChild(aClose);
    aClose.appendChild(textClose);

    //message close action
    aClose.onclick =  function() {
        on_message_close (messageDiv);
        return false;
    };
}

function on_message_close (messageDiv) {
    document.removeChild (messageDiv);
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why **document.removeChild (messageDiv);** does not remove the div as expected.

on_message_close is called, messageDiv is passed correctly, is an immediate child of document and it is a div.

**edit**
Found the solution:

```
function on_message_close (messageDiv) {
    alert (messageDiv.getAttribute("id"));
    parent = messageDiv.parentNode
    parent.removeChild (messageDiv);
}
```

I thought I'd tried that before asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) method only removes DOM objects that are direct children of the element.

> If child is actually not a child of the element node, the method throws an exception.

Comment: Could you explain that a little?

Comment: Each element has a list of children. If the child you are trying to remove is not one of those children, it will not be removed. That is, grandchildren and so on are not considered for removal. I provided a link in my answer for further reference.